# How do I copy and paste a range between two HTML text strings into an outlook email

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I'm trying to write a macro that will copy and paste a range into an Outlook email between two text strings.  I have text and formatting that I would like to include below and above the range that is pasted in the email.

```
Sub sendEmailwithPic()

Dim OutApp As Object
Dim Outmail As Object
Dim table As Range
Dim pic As Picture
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim wordDoc


Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set Outmail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

'grab table, convert to image, and cut
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Set table = ws.Range("A1:E11")
ws.Activate
table.Copy
Set pic = ws.Pictures.Paste
pic.Cut

'create email message
On Error Resume Next
    With Outmail
        .To = "someone@gmail.com"
        .Subject = "Country Population Data " & Format(Date, "mm-dd-yy")
        .Display
        
        
        Set wordDoc = Outmail.GetInspector.WordEditor
        wordDoc.Range.PasteandFormat wdChartPicture
        textStr1 = "<p><font style=font-size:11pt;font-family:Calibri><b>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</b></font></p>"
        textStr = "<body style=font-size:11pt;font-family:Calibri>" & _
                "<p><font style=font-size:11pt;font-family:Calibri><b>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit," & _
                "sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Vitae ultricies leo integer malesuada nunc.</b></p>" & _
                "<p><font style=font-size:9pt;font-family:Calibri>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit," & _
                "sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>" & _
                "<p><font style=font-size:9pt;font-family:Arial;color:#595959><i>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit," & _
                "sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Amet consectetur adipiscing elit ut. Mattis aliquam faucibus purus in massa tempor." & _
                "Hendrerit dolor magna eget est.</i></font></p>"
        
        .HTMLBody = textStr1 & textStr
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0
    
Set OutApp = Nothing
Set Outmail = Nothing

End Sub
```

When the macro compiles the email that is displayed looks like this:
[image]

However, my desired outcome is this:
[image]

Can someone please let me know what I'm doing wrong??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the HTML first, then use the Word object model to find and replace a placeholder with the pasted image.

Try this:

```vb
Sub sendEmailwithPic()

    Dim OutApp As Object, Outmail As Object
    Dim pic As Picture, wordDoc As Object, rng As Object, textStr1, textStr
    
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set Outmail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
    
    'grab table, convert to image, and cut
    With ThisWorkBook.Sheets("Sheet1")
        .Range("A1:E11").Copy
        Set pic = .Pictures.Paste
    End With
    pic.Cut

    With Outmail
        .To = "someone@gmail.com"
        .Subject = "Country Population Data " & Format(Date, "mm-dd-yy")
        
        textStr1 = "<p><font style=font-size:11pt;font-family:Calibri>" & _
            "<b>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</b></font></p>"
        
        textStr = "<p><font style=font-size:11pt;font-family:Calibri><b>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit," & _
                "sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Vitae ultricies leo integer malesuada nunc.</b></p>" & _
                "<p><font style=font-size:9pt;font-family:Calibri>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit," & _
                "sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>" & _
                "<p><font style=font-size:9pt;font-family:Arial;color:#595959><i>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit," & _
                "sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Amet consectetur adipiscing elit ut. Mattis aliquam faucibus purus in massa tempor." & _
                "Hendrerit dolor magna eget est.</i></font></p>"
        
        'first add the text, including a placeholder for the image...
        .HTMLBody = "<body style=font-size:11pt;font-family:Calibri>" & _
                    textStr1 & "{picHere}" & textStr
        .Display
        
        Set wordDoc = Outmail.GetInspector.WordEditor
        'then find and replace the placeholder text with the pasted image
        Set rng = wordDoc.Range
        With rng.Find
            .Text = "{picHere}"
            .Replacement.Text = ""
            .MatchWholeWord = True
            If .Execute Then
                rng.Text = "" '### `rng` now points to the found text
                rng.PasteandFormat 13 'wdChartPicture if using late binding
            End If
        End With
    End With
    
    Set OutApp = Nothing
    Set Outmail = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Nice! Voted it up. It required a picture between two html slices and received what he need. If I remember well, I have a function (bases from Ron de Bruin, I think) able to transform a range in html and place it in a html table. I will search for it and place such a version answer. Not what he requested, indeed... :)

Comment: c.f. modified mrexcel.com/board/threads/ron-de-bruin-rangetohtml.485720

Answer (score 1):

The next version (your adapted code) will not place a picture of the range, it will place the range in a html table (editable...):

```
Sub sendEmailwithTable()
 Dim OutApp As Object, Outmail As Object
 Dim ws As Worksheet, table As Range

 Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
 Set Outmail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

 'grab table range
 Set ws = ActiveSheet ' ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
 Set table = ws.Range("A1:E11")

'create email message
 Dim textStr1 As String, textstr As String
    With Outmail
        .To = "fane@tradeestcom.ro"
        .Subject = "Country Population Data " & Format(Date, "mm-dd-yy")
        .Display

        textStr1 = "<p><font style=font-size:11pt;font-family:Calibri><b>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</b></font></p>"
        textstr = "<body style=font-size:11pt;font-family:Calibri>" & _
                "<p><font style=font-size:11pt;font-family:Calibri><b>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit," & _
                "sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Vitae ultricies leo integer malesuada nunc.</b></p>" & _
                "<p><font style=font-size:9pt;font-family:Calibri>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit," & _
                "sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>" & _
                "<p><font style=font-size:9pt;font-family:Arial;color:#595959><i>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit," & _
                "sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Amet consectetur adipiscing elit ut. Mattis aliquam faucibus purus in massa tempor." & _
                "Hendrerit dolor magna eget est.</i></font></p>"
        
         .HTMLBody = "<body style=font-size:11pt;font-family:Calibri>" & textStr1
         .HTMLBody = .HTMLBody & "<table style='Margin-Left:5pt' BORDER=""2"" bordercolor = ""#00ff00"">" & _
                           RangetoHTML(table) & "</Table>" & "<br>" & textstr
    End With
    
 Set OutApp = Nothing: Set Outmail = Nothing

End Sub

Function RangetoHTML(rng As Range) 'from Ron de Bruin site, if I remember well...
 Dim FSO As Object, ts As Object, TempFile As String, TempWB As Workbook

 TempFile = Environ$("temp") & "/" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy h-mm-ss") & ".htm"

 'Copy the range and create a new workbook to past the data in
 rng.Copy
 Set TempWB = Workbooks.Add(1)
 With TempWB.Sheets(1)
    .cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
    .cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False
    .cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False
    .cells(1).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    On Error Resume Next
     .DrawingObjects.Visible = True
     .DrawingObjects.Delete
    On Error GoTo 0
 End With
    
 'Publish the sheet to a htm file
 With TempWB.PublishObjects.Add( _
    SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
    FileName:=TempFile, _
    Sheet:=TempWB.Sheets(1).name, _
    Source:=TempWB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.address, _
                             HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)
    .Publish (True)
 End With

 'Read all data from the htm file into RangetoHTML
 Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
 Set ts = FSO.getFile(TempFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
    RangetoHTML = ts.ReadAll
 ts.Close
 RangetoHTML = VBA.Replace(RangetoHTML, "align=center x:publishsource=", _
                                               "align=left x:publishsource=")

 'Close TempWB
 TempWB.Close SaveChanges:=False

'Delete the htm file we used in this function
 Kill TempFile

 Set ts = Nothing: Set FSO = Nothing: Set TempWB = Nothing

End Function
```